# Question about reading some part of the input

Tags: c++

I want to construct a programm in c++. The input is of the following form
(a given integer) N
(they follow N lines of stuff)
For the time being I want to read only the integer N and ignore the following N lines of stuff. How can I perform this using scanf or similar kind of function?

Comment: `int N; std::cin >> N;`? What do you mean with _" ignore the following N lines of stuff"_? Don't read them, or read and discard them?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to read them.

Comment: Uhm, then what specifically is your problem? Don't read what you don't want to read?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to read anything but the first number on the top. How can I do that? I tried cin>> command but it still doesn't read it. (It printed me 0 while it was supposed to print 1.) . I searched on the web only to find that I can use the identifier %*s, but that's in C, not in C++. Do you have any advise to give me?

Comment: So the input is not being read? That's kind of the opposite of your original question. Please take some time to refresh [ask], review your question and show a [mre].

Comment: You got an answer for the question you asked here. In the comments it becomes apparent that you should have asked a different question. Please use the "Ask Question" for that. (I.e. please do not change this question to a different one.)

Comment: Churill, I want to read only the first number on the input. I don’t want the other lines to be read. Am I now clear? I think that in my original post I didn’t ask something different. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is read using `cin`.

```
int n;
cin >> n; // reads one integer from the input before first space character
```

Unless you read the other integers they are ignored automatically.

Comment: For a question like this, you have created the perfect answer.

Comment: So if the input has this integer and some other stuff, I use this well known commands and it automatically reads the first one as desired?

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis Yes, it does. However, for a `string` in C++, it'll read till the first `'\n' (or new-line)` character.